# Как работает этот алгоритм поиска максимального числа?

Tags: python

https://ideone.com/tGdnF6

```
def max(a):
    if len(a)==2:
        return a[0] if a[0]>a[1] else a[1]
    sub_max=max(a[1:])
    return a[0]if a[0]>sub_max else sub_max
print(max([10,7,5,6]))
```

Вроде как тут строится "пирамидка" и на 3 шаге программы должна прерываться и выводиться наибольшее число , 
 которое находилось на вершине "пирамиды". Но выводится 10 . Программа взята из учебника и она верная , просто я не понимаю последовательность шагов компьютера .
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Программа ищет максимальное число в массиве и успешно находит. В чём проблема?

Answer (score 1):

`return` выходит не из всех уровней рекурсии, а только из одного. Возвращаемое значение попадает в присваивание в месте вызова и вычисления продолжаются.

А функция ищет максимальное значение в массиве, с чем вполне справляется.